# Strongly typed Azure Mobile Service table object by type or type string?

Tags: c#, azure, reflection, azure-mobile-services, strong-typing

I want to use a singular mobile service for a few applications. I want each of them to use the same class (namely 'Log'), but I want the info on the server back-end to go to a separate table. I am doing this from a Portable Class Library.

One option would be to use [DataTable(string)] attribute; however, I want for the whole thing to be automated (i.e. single DLL to include in the project that will automatically construct the table name from the context, i.e. string + "Log"). I couldn't find a way to modify the DataTable attribute run-time to get the reference to the strongly typed table.

Do I have other options than to use a weakly typed table and serialize JSON myself or is it possible to create a strongly typed reference based on the Type or Type name alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change the name of the data table based on some information in the runtime (this feature exists in the Android SDK, so you can consider [creating a feature request](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services) to have it added to the managed SDK as well).

What you can do, however, is to use a message handler which can "tweak" the request URI for table-related operations, so that you can achieve this programmatically. Basically, your portable library would expose, in addition to the data type you want shared across multiple applications, a class extending from `DelegatingHandler` which does that. Below is an example of such handler.

```
public class AppSpecificTableNamesHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public const string TablePrefix = "MyType";
    private const string TablesPathPrefix = "/tables/";

    private string tableSuffix;
    public AppSpecificTableNamesHandler(string tableSuffix)
    {
        this.tableSuffix = tableSuffix;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
        string path = uriBuilder.Path;
        if (path.StartsWith(TablesPathPrefix + TablePrefix))
        {
            path = TablesPathPrefix + TablePrefix +
                this.tableSuffix + path.Substring(TablesPathPrefix.Length + TablePrefix.Length);
            uriBuilder.Path = path;
            request.RequestUri = uriBuilder.Uri;
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

You can find the full code for the solution I used to test that (at least the most important classes) at https://gist.github.com/carlosfigueira/9582c08851d116f5a426.